# Как сделать, что бы после метода setTranslationX положение элемента осталось неизменно?

Tags: android, button

Мне нужно переместить кнопку. Я это делаю с помощью метода `setTranslationX()`. Но как потом сделать, что бы кнопка осталась в том же положении, в которое переместилась, а не возвращалась обратно?

Comment: записать в настройки getTranslationX кнопки и в onResume выставлять положение из настроек

Comment: можете пожалуйста подробнее объяснить?

Comment: а когда она у вас "возвращается"?

Comment: у меня ViewPager .состоит из 2 view. в момент, кода я перелистываю с 1 вью ко второму, вместе с этим двигается кнопка. Я это делаю с помощью метода setTranslationX(). но когда я полностью уже полностью на втором вью кнопка возвращается на первоначальное положение

Answer (score 1):

решение моей проблемы такое: `button.animate().translationXBy(movingDistance).start();`